# how to use redismetricrepository in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on spring boot actuator and able to see the metrics of my application. But I want to store these metrics to some db. In Spring doc it has been mentioned that RedisMetricRepository provides option for storing metrics to redis db. But I dont how to make use of this RedisMetricRepository to store metrics to redis db.Kindly help me out how to use RedisMetricRepository for storing metrics to redis db.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a `@Bean` of type `RedisMetricRepository`. I suspect that will just store the metrics in Redis immediately. I prefer to buffer in memory and export to Redis periodically. Here's a sample using `@Scheduled` to export to Redis every 5s): https://github.com/scratches/aggregator/blob/master/generator/src/main/java/demo/GeneratorApplication.java#L61.